# Make <div> element fill another <div> element

Tags: html, css

I'm facing the following problem:
I'm trying to make a div-element fit the remaining space in another div-element.
I've attached the jsfiddle for your convenience.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/P2898/

In this example you can see that the red square is outside the black square (because i used height: 100% and gave the red square an offset).

How do i make sure that the red square is just filling the black square, but doesn't go outside of it?

ps: the yellow square cannot be changed (so that needs to be 50px, no percentage).

css file:

```
#boundaries
{
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  height: 90%;
  width: 95%;
}

#top
{
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}

#bot
{
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  background: red;           
}
```

html-code:

```
<div id="boundaries">
   <div id="top">
      top
   </div>

   <div id="bot">
      bot
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use [`display:table`](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/P2898/3/) or [absolute positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/P2898/10/)

Comment: @Pete, You could add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) so that you ou can perform calculations to determine CSS height.

So in your example you want the red square to have `height` equal to black square height(100%) minus the height(50px) and the padding (20px+20px) of the yellow square.

Or you can play with values and adjust height based on your needs

Try:

```
#bot
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
    height: -o-calc(100% - 90px);
    height: calc(100% - 90px);
    width: 90%;
    background: red;           
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P2898/12/)

Comment: Good alternative to display table. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following styles:

```
#boundaries
{
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    height: 90%;
    width: 95%;
    display:table;
    border-spacing:20px;
}

#top
{
    display:table-row;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}

#bot
{
    display:table-row;
    background: red;           
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/P2898/3/)

But this will give you a margin of 20px all round the boxes - if you are wanting your inner boxes to stay at the 90% width, you can go the absolute positioning route:

```
#bot
{
    position: absolute;
    top:90px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:20px;
    width: 90%;
    background: red;           
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/P2898/10/)

Answer (score 0):

you need use `display: table;` `display: table-row;`

```
#boundaries
{
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    height: 90%;
    width: 95%;
    display:table;
    border-spacing:20px;
}

#top
{
    display:table-row;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}

#bot
{
    display:table-row;
    background: red;           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#boundaries
{
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    height: 90%;
    width: 95%;
}

#top
{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 20px;
    background: yellow;
}

#bot
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

Like so?

http://jsfiddle.net/P2898/11/

Comment: no, sorry, the red block has to be inside the black one

Comment: It is? http://puu.sh/ayDac/57637c468d.png

Comment: no: http://jsfiddle.net/FSwMu/

Comment: Jonathon. You haven't posted  the same code as me. #bot is missing width: 100%;

Comment: of course, setting the width of the red block to 90% shows that the black square is not fully under the red square... What i want is that the red square is completely in the black square.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation with absolute positioning seemed simple enough to me:

```
/* top and boundaries remain the same. */
#bot
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 70px;
    width: 90%;
    background: red;
}
```

This div is absolutely positioned and then the top is set so that it clears the top div, and `bottom: 0px;` forces it's height.

*Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/n2EYp/](http://jsfiddle.net/n2EYp/_)*

Comment: sorry, didn't state thin but position has to stay relative, thanks for your time anyway!